# Mathematica simplification and acceleration

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, simplification

I have been trying to integrate a function AND get an output that is sufficiently simple as to be usable. Simply using the `Simplify` and `FullSimplify` commands has not done nearly enough, and it takes me over 2 hours to get a result from this integration. Are there any further tricks I can use to force further simplifications? Any assumptions I can put in to make it simpler or faster?

Be warned, the example output is stupidly long, so much so that it is impossible to read, much less manually simplify.

EDIT: Updated input and output to reflect help from commentators. Still nowhere near being usable.

Input (ai, bi, ci,and di are unit vectors, and so will be replaced with the appropriate cosine later. ki has a value but is still kept track of so the proper cosine can be used later. the cosines are independent of the integration, so it makes it marginally shorter to do it this way):

```
 r = {r1, r2, r3};
a = {a1, a2, a3}/\[Sigma]a;
b = {b1, b2, b3}/\[Sigma]b;
c = {c1, c2, c3}/\[Sigma]c;
d = {d1, d2, d3}/\[Sigma]d;
k = {k1, k2, k3};
S = {{S11, S12, S13}, {S21, S22, S23}, {S31, S32, S33}};
FullSimplify[Integrate[(1/(2*Pi*\[Sigma]a*\[Sigma]b))*Exp[-(1/2)*((a.r)^2 + (b.r)^2)]*(1/(2*Pi*\[Sigma]c*\[Sigma]d))*Exp[-(1/2)*((c.r)^2 + (d.r)^2)], {r1, -Infinity, Infinity}, {r2, -Infinity, Infinity}, {r3, -Infinity, Infinity}, Assumptions -> Element[{r1, r2, r3, a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3, c1, c2, c3, d1, d2, d3, k1, k2, k3, S11, S12, S13, S21, S22, S23, S31, S32, S33, \[Sigma]a, \[Sigma]b, \[Sigma]c, \[Sigma]d, \[Tau]}, Reals] && \[Sigma]a > 0 && \[Sigma]b > 0 && \[Sigma]c > 0 && \[Sigma]d > 0 && \[Tau] >= 0 && 1 >= a1 >= -1 && 1 >= a2 >= -1 && 1 >= a3 >= -1 && 1 >= b1 >= -1 && 1 >= b2 >= -1 && 1 >= b3 >= -1 && 1 >= c1 >= -1 && 1 >= c2 >= -1 && 1 >= c3 >= -1 && 1 >= d1 >= -1 && 1 >= d2 >= -1 && 1 >= d3 >= -1]]]]
```

Output:

```
   ConditionalExpression[
 1/(Sqrt[2 \[Pi]] \[Sqrt]((b3^2 c2^2 d1^2 \[Sigma]a^2 - 
         2 b2 b3 c2 c3 d1^2 \[Sigma]a^2 + 
         b2^2 c3^2 d1^2 \[Sigma]a^2 - 
         2 b3^2 c1 c2 d1 d2 \[Sigma]a^2 + 
         2 b2 b3 c1 c3 d1 d2 \[Sigma]a^2 + 
         2 b1 b3 c2 c3 d1 d2 \[Sigma]a^2 - 
         2 b1 b2 c3^2 d1 d2 \[Sigma]a^2 + 
         b3^2 c1^2 d2^2 \[Sigma]a^2 - 2 b1 b3 c1 c3 d2^2 \[Sigma]a^2 +
          b1^2 c3^2 d2^2 \[Sigma]a^2 + 
         2 b2 b3 c1 c2 d1 d3 \[Sigma]a^2 - 
         2 b1 b3 c2^2 d1 d3 \[Sigma]a^2 - 
         2 b2^2 c1 c3 d1 d3 \[Sigma]a^2 + 
         2 b1 b2 c2 c3 d1 d3 \[Sigma]a^2 - 
         2 b2 b3 c1^2 d2 d3 \[Sigma]a^2 + 
         2 b1 b3 c1 c2 d2 d3 \[Sigma]a^2 + 
         2 b1 b2 c1 c3 d2 d3 \[Sigma]a^2 - 
         2 b1^2 c2 c3 d2 d3 \[Sigma]a^2 + 
         b2^2 c1^2 d3^2 \[Sigma]a^2 - 2 b1 b2 c1 c2 d3^2 \[Sigma]a^2 +
          b1^2 c2^2 d3^2 \[Sigma]a^2 + a3^2 c2^2 d1^2 \[Sigma]b^2 - 
         2 a2 a3 c2 c3 d1^2 \[Sigma]b^2 + 
         a2^2 c3^2 d1^2 \[Sigma]b^2 - 
         2 a3^2 c1 c2 d1 d2 \[Sigma]b^2 + 
         2 a2 a3 c1 c3 d1 d2 \[Sigma]b^2 + 
         2 a1 a3 c2 c3 d1 d2 \[Sigma]b^2 - 
         2 a1 a2 c3^2 d1 d2 \[Sigma]b^2 + 
         a3^2 c1^2 d2^2 \[Sigma]b^2 - 2 a1 a3 c1 c3 d2^2 \[Sigma]b^2 +
          a1^2 c3^2 d2^2 \[Sigma]b^2 + 
         2 a2 a3 c1 c2 d1 d3 \[Sigma]b^2 - 
         2 a1 a3 c2^2 d1 d3 \[Sigma]b^2 - 
         2 a2^2 c1 c3 d1 d3 \[Sigma]b^2 + 
         2 a1 a2 c2 c3 d1 d3 \[Sigma]b^2 - 
         2 a2 a3 c1^2 d2 d3 \[Sigma]b^2 + 
         2 a1 a3 c1 c2 d2 d3 \[Sigma]b^2 + 
         2 a1 a2 c1 c3 d2 d3 \[Sigma]b^2 - 
         2 a1^2 c2 c3 d2 d3 \[Sigma]b^2 + 
         a2^2 c1^2 d3^2 \[Sigma]b^2 - 2 a1 a2 c1 c2 d3^2 \[Sigma]b^2 +
          a1^2 c2^2 d3^2 \[Sigma]b^2 + a3^2 b2^2 d1^2 \[Sigma]c^2 - 
         2 a2 a3 b2 b3 d1^2 \[Sigma]c^2 + 
         a2^2 b3^2 d1^2 \[Sigma]c^2 - 
         2 a3^2 b1 b2 d1 d2 \[Sigma]c^2 + 
         2 a2 a3 b1 b3 d1 d2 \[Sigma]c^2 + 
         2 a1 a3 b2 b3 d1 d2 \[Sigma]c^2 - 
         2 a1 a2 b3^2 d1 d2 \[Sigma]c^2 + 
         a3^2 b1^2 d2^2 \[Sigma]c^2 - 2 a1 a3 b1 b3 d2^2 \[Sigma]c^2 +
          a1^2 b3^2 d2^2 \[Sigma]c^2 + 
         2 a2 a3 b1 b2 d1 d3 \[Sigma]c^2 - 
         2 a1 a3 b2^2 d1 d3 \[Sigma]c^2 - 
         2 a2^2 b1 b3 d1 d3 \[Sigma]c^2 + 
         2 a1 a2 b2 b3 d1 d3 \[Sigma]c^2 - 
         2 a2 a3 b1^2 d2 d3 \[Sigma]c^2 + 
         2 a1 a3 b1 b2 d2 d3 \[Sigma]c^2 + 
         2 a1 a2 b1 b3 d2 d3 \[Sigma]c^2 - 
         2 a1^2 b2 b3 d2 d3 \[Sigma]c^2 + 
         a2^2 b1^2 d3^2 \[Sigma]c^2 - 2 a1 a2 b1 b2 d3^2 \[Sigma]c^2 +
          a1^2 b2^2 d3^2 \[Sigma]c^2 + (a3 b2 c1 - a2 b3 c1 - 
            a3 b1 c2 + a1 b3 c2 + a2 b1 c3 - 
            a1 b2 c3)^2 \[Sigma]d^2)/(c3^2 (d2^2 \[Sigma]a^2 \
\[Sigma]b^2 + (b2^2 \[Sigma]a^2 + a2^2 \[Sigma]b^2) \[Sigma]d^2) - 
         2 c2 c3 (d2 d3 \[Sigma]a^2 \[Sigma]b^2 + (b2 b3 \[Sigma]a^2 +
                a2 a3 \[Sigma]b^2) \[Sigma]d^2) + 
         c2^2 (d3^2 \[Sigma]a^2 \[Sigma]b^2 + (b3^2 \[Sigma]a^2 + 
               a3^2 \[Sigma]b^2) \[Sigma]d^2) + \[Sigma]c^2 ((a3 d2 - 
               a2 d3)^2 \[Sigma]b^2 + 
            b3^2 (d2^2 \[Sigma]a^2 + a2^2 \[Sigma]d^2) - 
            2 b2 b3 (d2 d3 \[Sigma]a^2 + a2 a3 \[Sigma]d^2) + 
            b2^2 (d3^2 \[Sigma]a^2 + a3^2 \[Sigma]d^2)))) Sqrt[
    c3^2 (d2^2 \[Sigma]a^2 \[Sigma]b^2 + (b2^2 \[Sigma]a^2 + 
           a2^2 \[Sigma]b^2) \[Sigma]d^2) - 
     2 c2 c3 (d2 d3 \[Sigma]a^2 \[Sigma]b^2 + (b2 b3 \[Sigma]a^2 + 
           a2 a3 \[Sigma]b^2) \[Sigma]d^2) + 
     c2^2 (d3^2 \[Sigma]a^2 \[Sigma]b^2 + (b3^2 \[Sigma]a^2 + 
           a3^2 \[Sigma]b^2) \[Sigma]d^2) + \[Sigma]c^2 ((a3 d2 - 
           a2 d3)^2 \[Sigma]b^2 + 
        b3^2 (d2^2 \[Sigma]a^2 + a2^2 \[Sigma]d^2) - 
        2 b2 b3 (d2 d3 \[Sigma]a^2 + a2 a3 \[Sigma]d^2) + 
        b2^2 (d3^2 \[Sigma]a^2 + 
           a3^2 \[Sigma]d^2))]), (c3^2 (d2^2 \[Sigma]a^2 \[Sigma]b^2 \
+ (b2^2 \[Sigma]a^2 + a2^2 \[Sigma]b^2) \[Sigma]d^2) - 
      2 c2 c3 (d2 d3 \[Sigma]a^2 \[Sigma]b^2 + (b2 b3 \[Sigma]a^2 + 
            a2 a3 \[Sigma]b^2) \[Sigma]d^2) + 
      c2^2 (d3^2 \[Sigma]a^2 \[Sigma]b^2 + (b3^2 \[Sigma]a^2 + 
            a3^2 \[Sigma]b^2) \[Sigma]d^2) + \[Sigma]c^2 ((a3 d2 - 
            a2 d3)^2 \[Sigma]b^2 + 
         b3^2 (d2^2 \[Sigma]a^2 + a2^2 \[Sigma]d^2) - 
         2 b2 b3 (d2 d3 \[Sigma]a^2 + a2 a3 \[Sigma]d^2) + 
         b2^2 (d3^2 \[Sigma]a^2 + 
            a3^2 \[Sigma]d^2))) (b1^2 c3^2 d2^2 \[Sigma]a^2 - 
      2 b1^2 c2 c3 d2 d3 \[Sigma]a^2 + b1^2 c2^2 d3^2 \[Sigma]a^2 + 
      a3^2 c2^2 d1^2 \[Sigma]b^2 - 2 a2 a3 c2 c3 d1^2 \[Sigma]b^2 + 
      a2^2 c3^2 d1^2 \[Sigma]b^2 - 2 a3^2 c1 c2 d1 d2 \[Sigma]b^2 + 
      2 a2 a3 c1 c3 d1 d2 \[Sigma]b^2 + 
      2 a1 a3 c2 c3 d1 d2 \[Sigma]b^2 - 
      2 a1 a2 c3^2 d1 d2 \[Sigma]b^2 + a3^2 c1^2 d2^2 \[Sigma]b^2 - 
      2 a1 a3 c1 c3 d2^2 \[Sigma]b^2 + a1^2 c3^2 d2^2 \[Sigma]b^2 + 
      2 a2 a3 c1 c2 d1 d3 \[Sigma]b^2 - 
      2 a1 a3 c2^2 d1 d3 \[Sigma]b^2 - 
      2 a2^2 c1 c3 d1 d3 \[Sigma]b^2 + 
      2 a1 a2 c2 c3 d1 d3 \[Sigma]b^2 - 
      2 a2 a3 c1^2 d2 d3 \[Sigma]b^2 + 
      2 a1 a3 c1 c2 d2 d3 \[Sigma]b^2 + 
      2 a1 a2 c1 c3 d2 d3 \[Sigma]b^2 - 
      2 a1^2 c2 c3 d2 d3 \[Sigma]b^2 + a2^2 c1^2 d3^2 \[Sigma]b^2 - 
      2 a1 a2 c1 c2 d3^2 \[Sigma]b^2 + a1^2 c2^2 d3^2 \[Sigma]b^2 + 
      a3^2 b1^2 d2^2 \[Sigma]c^2 - 2 a2 a3 b1^2 d2 d3 \[Sigma]c^2 + 
      a2^2 b1^2 d3^2 \[Sigma]c^2 + a3^2 b1^2 c2^2 \[Sigma]d^2 - 
      2 a2 a3 b1^2 c2 c3 \[Sigma]d^2 + a2^2 b1^2 c3^2 \[Sigma]d^2 + 
      b3^2 ((a2 d1 - a1 d2)^2 \[Sigma]c^2 + 
         c2^2 (d1^2 \[Sigma]a^2 + a1^2 \[Sigma]d^2) - 
         2 c1 c2 (d1 d2 \[Sigma]a^2 + a1 a2 \[Sigma]d^2) + 
         c1^2 (d2^2 \[Sigma]a^2 + a2^2 \[Sigma]d^2)) + 
      b2^2 ((a3 d1 - a1 d3)^2 \[Sigma]c^2 + 
         c3^2 (d1^2 \[Sigma]a^2 + a1^2 \[Sigma]d^2) - 
         2 c1 c3 (d1 d3 \[Sigma]a^2 + a1 a3 \[Sigma]d^2) + 
         c1^2 (d3^2 \[Sigma]a^2 + a3^2 \[Sigma]d^2)) - 
      2 b1 b2 (-c3 (c2 d1 + c1 d2) d3 \[Sigma]a^2 + (a3 d1 - 
            a1 d3) (a3 d2 - a2 d3) \[Sigma]c^2 - 
         a3 (a2 c1 + a1 c2) c3 \[Sigma]d^2 + 
         c3^2 (d1 d2 \[Sigma]a^2 + a1 a2 \[Sigma]d^2) + 
         c1 c2 (d3^2 \[Sigma]a^2 + a3^2 \[Sigma]d^2)) - 
      2 b3 (b1 (-c2 d2 (c3 d1 + c1 d3) \[Sigma]a^2 + (a2 d1 - 
               a1 d2) (-a3 d2 + a2 d3) \[Sigma]c^2 - 
            a2 c2 (a3 c1 + a1 c3) \[Sigma]d^2 + 
            c1 c3 (d2^2 \[Sigma]a^2 + a2^2 \[Sigma]d^2) + 
            c2^2 (d1 d3 \[Sigma]a^2 + a1 a3 \[Sigma]d^2)) + 
         b2 (c2 d1 (c3 d1 - c1 d3) \[Sigma]a^2 + (a2 d1 - 
               a1 d2) (a3 d1 - a1 d3) \[Sigma]c^2 + 
            a1 c2 (-a3 c1 + a1 c3) \[Sigma]d^2 - 
            c1 c3 (d1 d2 \[Sigma]a^2 + a1 a2 \[Sigma]d^2) + 
            c1^2 (d2 d3 \[Sigma]a^2 + a2 a3 \[Sigma]d^2)))) > 0 || 
  2 Abs[Arg[(b1^2 c3^2 d2^2 \[Sigma]a^2 - 
         2 b1^2 c2 c3 d2 d3 \[Sigma]a^2 + b1^2 c2^2 d3^2 \[Sigma]a^2 +
          a3^2 c2^2 d1^2 \[Sigma]b^2 - 
         2 a2 a3 c2 c3 d1^2 \[Sigma]b^2 + 
         a2^2 c3^2 d1^2 \[Sigma]b^2 - 
         2 a3^2 c1 c2 d1 d2 \[Sigma]b^2 + 
         2 a2 a3 c1 c3 d1 d2 \[Sigma]b^2 + 
         2 a1 a3 c2 c3 d1 d2 \[Sigma]b^2 - 
         2 a1 a2 c3^2 d1 d2 \[Sigma]b^2 + 
         a3^2 c1^2 d2^2 \[Sigma]b^2 - 2 a1 a3 c1 c3 d2^2 \[Sigma]b^2 +
          a1^2 c3^2 d2^2 \[Sigma]b^2 + 
         2 a2 a3 c1 c2 d1 d3 \[Sigma]b^2 - 
         2 a1 a3 c2^2 d1 d3 \[Sigma]b^2 - 
         2 a2^2 c1 c3 d1 d3 \[Sigma]b^2 + 
         2 a1 a2 c2 c3 d1 d3 \[Sigma]b^2 - 
         2 a2 a3 c1^2 d2 d3 \[Sigma]b^2 + 
         2 a1 a3 c1 c2 d2 d3 \[Sigma]b^2 + 
         2 a1 a2 c1 c3 d2 d3 \[Sigma]b^2 - 
         2 a1^2 c2 c3 d2 d3 \[Sigma]b^2 + 
         a2^2 c1^2 d3^2 \[Sigma]b^2 - 2 a1 a2 c1 c2 d3^2 \[Sigma]b^2 +
          a1^2 c2^2 d3^2 \[Sigma]b^2 + a3^2 b1^2 d2^2 \[Sigma]c^2 - 
         2 a2 a3 b1^2 d2 d3 \[Sigma]c^2 + a2^2 b1^2 d3^2 \[Sigma]c^2 +
          a3^2 b1^2 c2^2 \[Sigma]d^2 - 
         2 a2 a3 b1^2 c2 c3 \[Sigma]d^2 + a2^2 b1^2 c3^2 \[Sigma]d^2 +

         b3^2 ((a2 d1 - a1 d2)^2 \[Sigma]c^2 + 
            c2^2 (d1^2 \[Sigma]a^2 + a1^2 \[Sigma]d^2) - 
            2 c1 c2 (d1 d2 \[Sigma]a^2 + a1 a2 \[Sigma]d^2) + 
            c1^2 (d2^2 \[Sigma]a^2 + a2^2 \[Sigma]d^2)) + 
         b2^2 ((a3 d1 - a1 d3)^2 \[Sigma]c^2 + 
            c3^2 (d1^2 \[Sigma]a^2 + a1^2 \[Sigma]d^2) - 
            2 c1 c3 (d1 d3 \[Sigma]a^2 + a1 a3 \[Sigma]d^2) + 
            c1^2 (d3^2 \[Sigma]a^2 + a3^2 \[Sigma]d^2)) - 
         2 b1 b2 (-c3 (c2 d1 + c1 d2) d3 \[Sigma]a^2 + (a3 d1 - 
               a1 d3) (a3 d2 - a2 d3) \[Sigma]c^2 - 
            a3 (a2 c1 + a1 c2) c3 \[Sigma]d^2 + 
            c3^2 (d1 d2 \[Sigma]a^2 + a1 a2 \[Sigma]d^2) + 
            c1 c2 (d3^2 \[Sigma]a^2 + a3^2 \[Sigma]d^2)) - 
         2 b3 (b1 (-c2 d2 (c3 d1 + c1 d3) \[Sigma]a^2 + (a2 d1 - 
                  a1 d2) (-a3 d2 + a2 d3) \[Sigma]c^2 - 
               a2 c2 (a3 c1 + a1 c3) \[Sigma]d^2 + 
               c1 c3 (d2^2 \[Sigma]a^2 + a2^2 \[Sigma]d^2) + 
               c2^2 (d1 d3 \[Sigma]a^2 + a1 a3 \[Sigma]d^2)) + 
            b2 (c2 d1 (c3 d1 - c1 d3) \[Sigma]a^2 + (a2 d1 - 
                  a1 d2) (a3 d1 - a1 d3) \[Sigma]c^2 + 
               a1 c2 (-a3 c1 + a1 c3) \[Sigma]d^2 - 
               c1 c3 (d1 d2 \[Sigma]a^2 + a1 a2 \[Sigma]d^2) + 
               c1^2 (d2 d3 \[Sigma]a^2 + 
                  a2 a3 \[Sigma]d^2))))/(c3^2 (d2^2 \[Sigma]a^2 \
\[Sigma]b^2 + (b2^2 \[Sigma]a^2 + a2^2 \[Sigma]b^2) \[Sigma]d^2) - 
         2 c2 c3 (d2 d3 \[Sigma]a^2 \[Sigma]b^2 + (b2 b3 \[Sigma]a^2 +
                a2 a3 \[Sigma]b^2) \[Sigma]d^2) + 
         c2^2 (d3^2 \[Sigma]a^2 \[Sigma]b^2 + (b3^2 \[Sigma]a^2 + 
               a3^2 \[Sigma]b^2) \[Sigma]d^2) + \[Sigma]c^2 ((a3 d2 - 
               a2 d3)^2 \[Sigma]b^2 + 
            b3^2 (d2^2 \[Sigma]a^2 + a2^2 \[Sigma]d^2) - 
            2 b2 b3 (d2 d3 \[Sigma]a^2 + a2 a3 \[Sigma]d^2) + 
            b2^2 (d3^2 \[Sigma]a^2 + a3^2 \[Sigma]d^2)))]] < \[Pi]]
```

Comment: Notice the condition is: x/y Element Reals && Re[ x/y ] >0 && 2Abs[ Arg[ x/y ] ] < Pi. So tell it each component of your unit vectors are Real. Then see if telling it what you know and it doesn't, that each ai,bi,ci,di are unit vectors helps. Then see if there is some simple way you can tell it that y is not zero and the signs of x and y are the same. With all that you might be able to then use Simplify instead of FullSimplify, which should be orders of magnitude faster, eliminate the condition making the result four times smaller and perhaps even give a far simpler result.

Comment: Some of your assumptions in your Integrate are not doing what you think they are. Compare a = {a1,a2,a3}; Assuming[Element[{a,b},Reals],
 Simplify[Sqrt[a1^2]]] which returns Sqrt[a1^2] with a = {a1,a2,a3}; 
Assuming[Element[{a1,b},Reals], Simplify[Sqrt[a1^2]]] which returns Abs[a1]. The first shows Mma thinks a1 is still complex while the second shows you have told it a1 is real. You are telling it to assume all your vectors and matricies are actually a Real number, not that every element of those are actually Real numbers.

Comment: Thanks Bill. I thought by association by telling it that the vector was real it would assume the components were all real.

Comment: Unfortunately That didn't make it simplify that much. Updating the original post with the new input and output.

Comment: The only thing that isn't in the assumptions is that ai, bi, ci, and di are all of the form 1>=ai>=-1 because they are cosine functions of the angle between directions a and i.

Comment: If i set $Assumptions= -1<=r1<=1&&-1<=r2<=1&&... for all your ri, ai, bi, ci, ki, Si, that tells Mma they are Real, and then Simplify your product of two exponentials I see each of your sigmas squared in a denominator. If you don't want divide by zero then your sigmas should be >0, not >=0. If make that change and then only integrate over r1, to inspect the smaller result, then I still get a ConditionalExpression where it needs one fraction==0 and another fraction>0. Look at your vector equations, verify that must be true and think of a way to tell Mathematica that it can simplify that away.

Comment: The r variables are not bounded in -1 to 1, they are the integration variables. Only the a, b, c, and d variables are so bounded. k and S stuff could have any real value.

Comment: Sorry for my bounds misunderstanding. If the form of your a,b,c,d are all the same then show one of them in cosine form and maybe I can find something. Other than that I am out of ideas to get it to automatically radically simplify this for you.